# Largest conjugacy class of $S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am familiar with the formula for computing the size of a conjugacy class of $S_n$ given its cycle type, but other than guessing and checking I do not know how to find either:

1. The size of the largest conjugacy class
2. The cycle type of the largest conjugacy class.

Is there any simple way of computing these?

Answer (score 4):

For each cycle type, there is a formula of how many elements are in this conjugacy class, e.g., for $(123\cdots n)$ we see that its conjugacy class has size $(n-1)!$. However, the conjugacy class of $(123\cdots n-1)(n)$ is bigger for $n\ge 3$, namely 
$$
(n-1)!+(n-2)!=\frac{n!}{n-1}.
$$

This is the largest size, if you look at the [Conjugacy class size formula in symmetric group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class_size_formula_in_symmetric_group). I don't know a simple way of computing it, since we have $p(n)$ conjugacy classes, i.e., cycle types, which grows rapidly with $n$. As for the computation of the size of the largest conjugacy class, see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001048/b001048.txt). It is mentioned, too, that this is the "the maximum entry in each row of A036039".

Comment: The OEIS entry A001048 (to which you linked) claims that the conjugacy class of $(123 \cdots n-1)(n)$ is maximal, but gives no proof.  However, maximizing the size of the conjugacy class is equivalent to minimizing the denominator $\prod_j j^{a_j} (a_j)!$ in that formula, where $a_1 + 2a_2 + \cdots + na_n = n$.  You're looking at $a_1 = 1, a_{n-1} = 1$, and $a_j = 0$ for all other $j$, giving the product $n-1$.   That this is the largest seems to be folklore, e.g. Stanley's comment at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84271/distribution-of-the-sizes-of-conjugacy-classes-in-the-symmetric-group

Comment: @MichaelLugo Thank you for your helpful comment, and the MO-link with Stanley's comment. I was trying to find some written proof.